# Google Street View Image API inconsistency from Javascript API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

Some images in the Image API sometimes doesn't exist as in JS API.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Image API example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x600&location=-22.8924809,-43.1787796&fov=110&heading=268.2&pitch=16.66&sensor=false

Streetview example:

https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-22.8924809,-43.1787796,3a,75y,226.52h,97.49t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-8NK-1RTB8HI%2FV3QjO_G0G_I%2FAAAAAAAAtHg%2F96qHyaKVyBUw8dvYLXH2sUUSoDbCqpJrQCJkC!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2F-8NK-1RTB8HI%2FV3QjO_G0G_I%2FAAAAAAAAtHg%2F96qHyaKVyBUw8dvYLXH2sUUSoDbCqpJrQCJkC%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya253.65114-ro0-fo100%2F!7i7168!8i3584

I also noticed a lot of cases where there are different versions of images, mostly the Image API have older versions, or bad stitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'non-Google' images don't seem to exist in the image API. Look at the bottom right of any Street View to see the attribution.